# Can we use jquery ajax to call web api(asp.net core) in angular 7 instead of using HTTP service?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, angular7, asp.net-core-webapi

**Can someone help me with this...??**
I want to call web api from asp.net core using jquery ajax call from .ts file.
1) Is it possible?
2) What are the pros and cons of it?
3) What are the pros of HTTP service over ajax call?

Comment: You're asking multiple questions, which can make the question "too broad".  In terms of using jQuery vs "HTTP service", if "HTTP service" involves making an http/https call to some server endpoint, then yes, jQuery can also do that.

Comment: However, you also have the question tagged with `angular`, so the bigger question would be why you want to use jQuery for ajax, rather than using Angular.

Comment: @Taplar thanks for replying. I just wanted to know if there is any harm in writing jquery in angular typescript file?

Comment: Harm?  No.  Bad practice?  Yes.  Angular already offers everything you need to make ajax calls.  Rather than relying on the crutch of jQuery, you need to become familiar with your framework and embrace what it offers you

Comment: Okay. I am new to angular, can you help me with some example of ajax resemblance in angular?

Comment: Unfortunately providing generic examples is typically off topic for questions on StackOverflow.  Questions are intended to specify a concrete problem, that can then be given an answer.  If you have a specific example of a problem you are having difficulty with, please edit your question to include it and reformulate your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. @Taplar